# extract untagged elements with symfony dom crawler

Tags: php, symfony, domcrawler

How to extract untagged elements with symfony dom crawler. For example in the sample html below I want to extract `Hello World`.

```
<strong>title</strong>Hello World<strong>Sub-Title</strong><div>This is just stuff</div>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could do this easily with [PHP DOM](http://php.net/manual/en/book.dom.php) ;)

```
$dom = new DOMDocument();
$dom->loadHTML('<strong>title</strong>Hello World<strong>Sub-Title</strong><div>This is just stuff</div>');
$xpath = new DOMXPath($dom);
// use the fact that PHP DOM wraps everything into the body and get the text()
$entries = $xpath->query('//body/text()');
foreach ($entries as $entry) {
    echo $entry->nodeValue;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

i have a better way for you

```
$ExtractText = $crawler->filter('strong')->eq(1)->text();
```

this pretty much get the  **tag of the index 1
as your ***title***** is index 0